# Uncaught exception: 1: An unknown error occurred thrown in Facebook API, FQL error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

When I try to do an [FQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Query_Language) to catch all the photos in a friend's checkins, I'm getting an unknown error from the Facebook API.

Here's my code:

```
$photo_params = array('method' => 'fql.query','query' => "SELECT attachment, post_id FROM stream WHERE post_id IN ( SELECT post_id FROM checkin WHERE author_uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()))",);
//Run query

$result_photo = $fbapi->api($photo_params);
```

I'll handle the attachment data to get the photo's URL then.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're using [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API) in a wrong way. The new way of doing FQL queries via Graph API is:

```
$query = "SELECT attachment, post_id FROM stream WHERE post_id IN ( SELECT post_id FROM checkin WHERE author_uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()))";
$result_photo = $fbapi->api('/fql', 'GET', array('q'=>$query));
```

Comment: not work, I'm still getting the wrong message, just in a different form
'Array ( [error_code] => 1 [error_msg] => An unknown error occurred )'

Comment: I check my code more deeply, I figure out the fql works fine till I select post_id from checkin, but failed when I want to grab the attachment data from stream table, still don't know why?